# How to find a particular string within another string as quickly as possible?

Tags: python, indexing

I'd like to know if there is a better/nicer/faster way to solve the following problem.

> Return True if the given string contains an appearance of "abc" where the abc is not directly preceded by a period (.). So "qabc" counts but "r.abc" does not count.

My solution was:

```
def abc_there(string):
    tmp = 0
    for i in xrange(len(string)):
        if string[i:i+3] == "abc" and string[i-1] != ".":
            tmp += 1
    return tmp > 0
```

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify:

".abc" --> False

".abcabc" --> True

only the instance next to the right of the period gets erased.

Comment: ...I would seriously consider using [a regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). But more seriously, get rid of tmp, replace `tmp += 1` with `return True` and `return tmp>0` with `return False`. You only need to find one occurrence to return true.

Comment: not necessarily if the string is ".abcabcabc" it would return True since only the first abc gets nullified

Comment: the `return False` would be outside of your for loop and would only fire if the `return True` never did.

Comment: Consider what the `if` statement checks when a string starts with `'abc'`...

Comment: I meant to say the function should return `True` in a scenario where the argument is ".abcabcabc"

Comment: If you want raw speed, why are you using Python? Readability counts.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are the perfect tool for doing this:

```
>>> import re
# Test if it contains a match
>>> bool(re.search(r'(?:^|[^.])(abc)', 'testabc funcabc'))
True
>>> bool(re.search(r'(?:^|[^.])(abc)', '.abc'))
False

# Count the number of occurrences
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|[^.])(abc)', 'abc testabc func.abc')
['abc', 'abc']
>>> len(re.findall(r'(?:^|[^.])(abc)', 'abc testabc func.abc'))
2
```

See the [Python documentation on the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more details.

Comment: You might consider switching the order of your examples since the poster asked specifically about the string containing `'abc'` and not counting the occurrences.

Comment: +1 for providing a sane, generalizeable approach *using the right tools*, instead of coming up with a premature optimization hack that ekes out every last nanosecond.

Comment: The regex in this solution in its current form returns false for "abcfsdfdsfdsfsdf". It doesn't detect a match at the start of the string.

Comment: @PurdeaAndrei ouch, that is a bug, I'm gonna fix this :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a less straight-forward way to do this problem
and it's slightly faster too. My code:

```
def xyz_there(string):
    return string.count(".abc") != string.count("abc")
```

This works because if there is a string passed as "abc.abc",
The ".abc" count would be 1
but the abc count would be 2
But if the string was just "fd.abc.abc" for example.
It would return False.

To prove it's faster, I headed over to IPython.

```
In [1]: def abc_there(string):
 ...:       tmp = 0
 ...:       for i in xrange(len(string)):
 ...:           if string[i:i+3] == "abc" and string[i-1] != ".":
 ...:               tmp += 1
 ...:       return tmp > 0

In [2]: timeit abc_there("nghkabc")
Out[2]: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 310 ns per loop

In [3]: def abc_there(string):
...:        return string.count(".abc") != string.count("abc")

In [4]: timeit abc_there("nghkabc")
Out[4]: 1000000 loops, best of 3: 296 ns per loop
```

296ns < 310ns so my solution was a bit faster.

Comment: But is it faster than using a regular expression?

Comment: yes, about times 3 I just tried with @piglei 's solution and it ran 906ns per loop

Comment: If you want the regex to run faster in a loop, then do this:  r = re.compile(r"xyz|.*[^.]xyz"); r.match(string)     And put only the r.match part in the loop

Comment: With re.compile it ran 368 ns still slower. Thanks for tbe comment thats good to know.

Comment: But if the `string` variable is **big**, this solution may be slower than the regular expression one. Because it needs to iterate over the whole string.

Comment: @PurdeaAndrei Not `re.match()`. `re.search()` instead.

Comment: @piglei I see what you're saying. Definitely makes sense. Dividoo should take that into account.

Comment: OK, but 14 billionths of sec (4.5%) isn't a very significant improvement over the OP's code IMHO.

Comment: @tsroten re.match appears to be faster then re.search

Comment: The real improvement comes when the search is done on a huge string that doesn't have any matches. In that case @El_Dorado's answer is the absolute best, because python is using efficient string search algorithms.

Comment: @martineau He asked for a faster solution I didn't say that's the way he should implement it. I agree that it's not a substantial amelioration, but its still a tad faster.

Comment: >>> timeit.timeit('xyz_there("---"* 5000)', 'def xyz_there(string): return string.count(".abc") != string.count("abc")', number=10000)
    0.0746450424194336
    >>> timeit.timeit('r.match("---" * 5000)', 'import re; r=re.compile(r"xyz|.*[^.]xyz")', number=10000)
    1.5958092212677002
    >>> _ / 0.0746450424194336
    21.37863640428767

Comment: @El_Dorado's solution is 20 times faster

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I should've added that I can't use outside libraries for the exercise....

Comment: Sure thing. Glad it helped :)

Comment: @PurdeaAndrei: Who's El_Dorado?

Comment: @martineau changed my SO name thats me.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of thing, regexes are probably the way to go. However, if you were to go with something like what you already have, you're still being insufficiently lazy.

```
def abc_there(string):
    if string[:3] == "abc": return True #case "abc" at start of string
    for i in xrange(1,len(string)):
        if string[i:i+3] == "abc" and string[i-1] != ".":
            return True #Hah! found something. I get to leave early!
    #if we make it out of the loop without finding something
    return False
```

Note that if any match is found, you'll return `True`; you only reach the `return False` if no match is found. In general, if you're writing a function that's checking something in an iterator, you want to stop and return as early as you can. (The builtins `any` and `all` are designed to do this, by the way.)

Oh, I guess, if you're ever checking something in an iterator, consider using `any` and `all` :P

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
re.match(r"abc|.*[^.]abc", string)
```

or for speed:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r"abc|.*[^.]abc")
r.match(string)
r.match(string2)
```

Comment: This regular expression seems overly complicated since you are using `re.match()`. See the [Python documentation discussion on `search()` vs. `match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: @tsroten an re.search regex would look like this:   `r"[^.]xyz|^xyz"`   Not much less comlpicated in my opinion. To be fair the re.match solution seems to be almost 3 times faster.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I didn't realize the speed difference would favor `match()` that much.